# Set Magento MySQL Connection to use SSL

Tags: configuration, mysql, security

We have a Magento site on a VM with 2GB of RAM.  Right now, both Apache and MySQL are running on that same VM.  Since that's just not enough RAM for this site, I have been tasked with separating the MySQL server onto a separate 2GB VM (which is running on a different host machine in the same datacenter).

Because the network between the two VMs is not secure, I want to use SSL on the MySQL connection between them.  I cannot seem to find how to tell Magento to use SSL.

I know that in PDO directly I would do something like this:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=ssldb',
    'username',
    'password',
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/path/to/client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/path/to/client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/path/to/ca-cert.pem'
    )
);
```

Where in the config file would I put those SSL options though?

Comment: I just found [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25011/setting-pdo-mysql-driver-options-through-local-xml) from earlier this year ... with no response :(.

Comment: Why not just grow the VM and save yourself the grief? Or move to a VM provider that supports private VLANs? Or if you must, use a VPN between the two and have many more benefits. The overhead of SSL with MySQL is significant (25% in Percona's testing, http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/10/mysql-ssl-performance-overhead/)

Comment: @choco-loo Because separate web and database servers is good practice and two VMs are what I've been given to do the job with.

Comment: My question was rhetorical :) It's certainly not good practice, it's the polar opposite of good practice. Magento is infinitely slower in a web+db configuration. At your scale, you would be far better pooling your resources, you would have better performance, better reliability, better security, ease of management etc.

Comment: @choco-loo It is definitely good practice.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659970/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-have-the-database-and-web-server-on-the-same-machine) among many other sources for some of the reasons why.  Having separate Web and Database servers is **required** in order to pass certain security audits.

Comment: It really isn't. You are blindly applying a legacy practice of service separation without understanding the impact of what you are doing and making an assumption it will be more secure and faster. The response given on that SO post is a "general" concept, it isn't applicable to your scenario. You have asked a question, specific to your situation - and I've taken the time to provide a response to help you make the right decision. Don't link to an irrelevant question/answer when you have just been given your own relevant, contextually correct answer.

Comment: Magento should be run on nothing less than 8GB RAM,  trying to squeeze it into 2GB is a really bad idea. You'll cripple performance, reliability will be none existent. Worse still, by separating your DB server, you have doubled your risk of failure (you now have 2 SPOFs), you have risked your security by doubling the surface attack area, you have constrained performance by limiting it to the (likely oversold) contended, shaped, QoSed network between the two - capping throughput and adding massive amounts of latency.

Comment: You would have been far better off merely growing your 2GB VM to 8GB. There would be an immediate benefit of pooled resources, performance will improve significantly (given there is no network to traverse), there is no risk of sending plain text data over a public network, you've got half the amount of servers to fail, your software configuration has no convoluted tunnels that will fail (or create bizarre packet mangling MTU issues) … the list goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I went with an SSH tunnel maintained with [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).  It may not be as performant as raw tcp, but my testing indicates that it is perfectly adequate for us (with room for future growth too).

We have already seen a significant performance boost now that the web server and the database server are no longer fighting for RAM *and disk IO*.

Answer (score 3):

Not really any clean solution for this as the class in question is under `lib` so you can't rewrite it as per a normal model etc.  Have a look at class `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract` and protected method `_connect()`.  This is where you will see the  call to `new PDO()` and where you need to make the changes.  As the only option for overriding this method is to move the entire class to the local codepool, there is better, much shorter class you can move instead.  Class `Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` extends off `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract` and as method `_connect()` is protected and not private you can copy it into the class and it will run instead of the Zend class method.

So copy `lib/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` to `app/code/local/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`, add the `_connect()` method from class `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract` and make the necessary changes to the `new PDO()` call.

Note that the classes here are only relevant from 1.8CE onwards - `lib/Magento/` didn't exist before that.  Also bear in mind moving core files to the local codepool is not a good way of doing things.  Even though it's the only real option that I can see in this case, it's still not good practice.